# How to change the scale of main text without affecting math text or viceversa?

Tags: fonts, scaling, libertine, fourier

I'm using `libertine` package for the main text of my work and I load `fourier` package before `libertine` in orther to get the math text with the Utopia font just because I like it. Typing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools}

\begin{document}
    s$\sin$nc$\cos$
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Predictably, the heights are different and I want to make them as similar as possible. A solution might be using the `erewhon` option of the `newtxmath` package, but some math symbols (like `\emptyset`) are so ugly in contrast to those from `fourier`. Also, according to the `libertine` documentation, there is an option called `llscale` but it's not actually defined in the `.sty` file.

I wonder if there's something that I can type in my preamble in orden to change the scale of the libertine font or the utopia font. I tried to read the `.sty` files of both packages to figure this out but I don't understand most of the things that are written in the files.

I'm using TeX Live 2017 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In libertine.sty in TeXLive 2018:

```
\DeclareOptionX{llscale}{\renewcommand*{\LinuxLibertineT@scale}{#1}}
```

Comment: I think this answer needs to be extended with some sort of explanation.

Comment: Perhaps the recommendation is load the `libertine` package with the option `llcscale=.95`? (Where the number needs to be found by trial and error, or by actually measuring the x-height of the two fonts.) If so, better say that, then.

Comment: The OP apparently read the documentation but either didn't believe it or is using an obsolete version: "according to the libertine documentation, there is an option called llscale but it's not actually defined in the .sty file"

Comment: Oh, I see. My guess is that the OP mistyped the option when searching for it – even though it is correctly spelled in the question. I thought it was `11scale` at first, and did not find that either. 8-)

Comment: I actually tried that option but I got the message `c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:210: LaTeX Error: Unknown option "llscale" for package "libertine"`. That's why I read the `.sty`.

Comment: But you're right. I read the documentation of the `libertine` package of TeX Live 2018 (where `llscale` option is mentioned) but the documentation that is in the `libertine` folder in my PC does not mention that option.

Comment: You could try adding the \DeclareOptionX line to your libertine.sty (with the other \DeclareOptionX commands) and it may work.

Comment: I just updated TeX Live and compare both `.sty` files from TeX Live 2017 and TeX Live 2018. It seem to be the that, besides the `\DeclareOptionX` that you mentioned, there's an extra option (`Scale`) in every command that defines the `libertine` font. Anyway, I wouldn't have been able to change that with a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` environment.

Comment: "I wouldn't have been able to change that with[out] a \makeatletter-\makeatother environment."  You can copy libertine.sty to your working folder and add that command there without \makeatletter-\makeatother